How to rotate the header except the two first columns?
I followed some questions R datatable rotate header not aligning, but I am not sure how I can add parameter start, end to the headerCallback. I do have some columns no need to rotate 180 degree.
headerCallback <- c(
  "function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  var $ths = $(thead).find('th');",
  "  $ths.css({'vertical-align': 'bottom', 'white-space': 'nowrap'});",
  "  var betterCells = [];",
  "  $ths.each(function(){",
  "    var cell = $(this);",
  "    var newDiv = $('<div>', {height: 'auto', width: cell.height()});",
  "    var newInnerDiv = $('<div>', {text: cell.text()});",
  "    newDiv.css({margin: 'auto'});",
  "    newInnerDiv.css({",
  "      transform: 'rotate(180deg)',",
  "      'writing-mode': 'tb-rl',",
  "      'white-space': 'nowrap'",
  "    });",
  "    newDiv.append(newInnerDiv);",
  "    betterCells.push(newDiv);",
  "  });",
  "  $ths.each(function(i){",
  "    $(this).html(betterCells[i]);",
  "  });",
  "}"
)

datatable(mtcars %>% mutate(name = row.names(mtcars),
                            id = row_number()) %>% select(id,name, everything()), 
          rownames = F, 
          class = list(stripe = FALSE),
          options = list(
            paging = F, autoWidth = F,
            searching= FALSE,
            scrollX = F,
            # initComplete = JS("function(settings, json) {
            #                     $(this.api().table().header()).css({
            #                       'font-size' : '12px'});}"),
            headerCallback = JS(headerCallback))) %>% 
  formatStyle(columns = c(1:10), `font-size` = '12px')



I couldn't get it to work using a callback method, but datatable is an htmlwidget, so I was able to make it work using htmlwidgets::onRender().
Most of the JS here is identical to the code in your question. The primary differences are that thead is no longer a variable...it is an element, so it's not too difficult to add quotes. However, when datatable builds, it essentially builds two tables, one for the header and one for the main table. Odd. So I've added first so that the first thead is the only one queried. That gets us to:
$('thead:first')

Then we have to find the th elements. I don't know how many headers you don't want to rotate, nor do I think you're using the mtcars data in your actual project, so I've an example of how you can do this, but if your need something more robust (e.g., you have 50 headers or something), let me know.
Within find, I've added criteria. Since it's likely that you're rotating more labels than not, I have used :not to remove a few labels from the code that rotates the labels. I've removed the first two in this table, so "id" and "name" using the element attribute aria-label. (As an example, this is the full attribute from the id header: aria-label="id: activate to sort column ascending".)
In the code, I've used ^= which equates to starts with + the label + ":".
That gets us to:
$('thead:first').find('th:not([aria-label^=\"id:\"], [aria-label^=\"name:\"])');

The \" is simply to escape the 3rd level of quotes needed here. In JS, you could use or not use the \" but you need it in R.
Here's the table and the JS altogether. The only difference in the R code is the removal of the callback function. The JS query is different, of course, along with variable names.
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

datatable(mtcars %>% mutate(name = row.names(mtcars),
                            id = row_number()) %>% select(id,name, everything()), 
          rownames = F, 
          class = list(stripe = FALSE),
          options = list(
            paging = F, autoWidth = F,
            searching= FALSE,
            scrollX = F
          )) %>% 
  formatStyle(columns = c(1:10), `font-size` = '12px') %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    "function(el, x) { /* don't move labels for id and name column */
      var $ths = $('thead:first').find('th:not([aria-label^=\"id:\"], [aria-label^=\"name:\"])');
      var newCells = [];
      $ths.each(function() {
        var cell = $(this);
        var newD = $('<div>', {height: 'auto', width: cell.height()});
        var newInD = $('<div>', {text: cell.text()});
        newD.css({margin: 'auto'});
        newInD.css({
          transform: 'rotate(180deg)',
          'writing-mode': 'tb-rl',
          'white-space': 'nowrap'
        });
        newD.append(newInD);
        newCells.push(newD);
      });
      $ths.each(function(i){
        $(this).html(newCells[i]);
      });
    }"
  )


